# How to show new line in the hint generated from comment in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

When using VS Code, I want my block comments shown with the new line when I move the cursor onto it. Currently it is presented in just one line as below. I did google online but didn't find anything related. Any advice would be appreciated!

**VSCode Version** 1.59.0

**Commit** 379476f0e13988d90fab105c5c19e7abc8b1dea8

**Related Issue** [C/C++ doc comments preview doesn't react to newlines](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/3464)
(Should be fixed yet)

[image]

Update 8.28:

(1) In my case, @brief, @param, etc have an effect of removing newline of the following statement, and Markdown grammar cannot be interpreted in my VS Code, e.g.

[image]

(2) The only way it works is using pure block comments like this:

[image]

Comment: bro its working fine for me, I think you are using some plugins. maybe that's the problem. your @brief text is blue and its not blue for me. I don't know if that the case

Comment: Thanks, I am indeed using Doxygen Documentation Generator but I tried disabling it and it doesn't work anyway. However it works when I remove the \@brief part, and it seems that newline is removed when displaying brief. And when I add \@param, it doesn't work again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience, in VS Code 1.76.2 you can separate paragraphs only in the `@note` section by adding more `@note`

[image: Note section adds paragraphs]

I don't have more extensions besides the default C/C++ by Microsoft

Comment: @jason-song, how's that a better answer than mine? Also a `@note` section does not render line breaks.

Comment: @MikeLischke Simply because your solution never works on my machine. I am sure your answer is probably useful for others though.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot influence how normal text is rendered. It's interpreted as Markdown text with collapsed whitespaces. The only way to do at least partially what you want is to format (a part of) the text as code, just like you can do here at Stackoverflow (triple back tick block):

````js
    /**
     * Converts the given position to one which is relative to this context.
     *
     * ```ts
     * let i: number = 1;
     * const a = true;
     * ```
     *
     * @param value The position to convert.
     *
     * @returns The position in local space.
     */
    public toLocal(value: IPosition): IPosition {
        return {
            lineNumber: value.lineNumber - this.presentation.startLine + 1,
            column: value.column,
        };
    }
````

[image]

Comment: Thank you Mike. Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me, and I suspect it depends on the environment, and later I will do more study on this

Answer (score 0):

Related to a previous answer in this issue - what worked for me, was to start and end a code example section, just to create a newline.
Not entirely sure if this is a good practice, but it works for me.

```` /**
 * this is some text.
 * ```
 * ```
 * this is some text on the next line.
 */ ````